# Android jumps around in some devices

Tags: java, android

I get an error when I run my app on some device emulators that is due to the code jumping around. In Galaxy S9, (tracing) the code jumps from

ordering = ... (above the switch statement)
directly into the switch statement to case 1:incompleteSearch
and then back to case 0:databaseAccess.getCursor_anagrams(term, filters, ordering);

where it errors out because term=""

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding with no difference.

```
private Cursor getCursor(int searchType) {
    EditText et = findViewById(R.id.etEntry);
    String term = et.getText().toString();

    Spinner beginnings = findViewById(R.id.BeginsWith);
    String begins = beginnings.getSelectedItem().toString();

    Spinner endings = findViewById(R.id.EndsWith);
    String ends = endings.getSelectedItem().toString();

    Spinner sp = findViewById(R.id.MinLength);

    if (!(searchType == 3)) {
        term = term.replaceAll("[cv*0123456789.,^+-]", "");
        et.setText(term);
    }

    String filters = makefilters(searchType);
    ordering = getSortOrder();

    // todo get from control, method
    databaseAccess.open();
    switch (searchType) {
        case 0:
            if (term != "")
                return databaseAccess.getCursor_anagrams(term, filters, ordering);
            else
                incompleteSearch();
            break;
        case 1:
            int count = sp.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
            etTerm.setText("");
            if (count > 1)
                return databaseAccess.getCursor_ByLetterCount(count, filters, ordering);
            else
                incompleteSearch();
            break;
```

Comment: What makes you say that the "code is jumping around"? I seriously doubt that

Comment: When I trace the code in debug mode it goes to those lines.

Comment: what makes you think that going to those lines means it is skipping the rest?

Comment: difficult to reproduce that. add verbose logging to gain a grasp what is actually going on.

Comment: I'm stepping through the code in debug mode.

Comment: I'm selecting the options that equate to searchType 0, with empty string term.

Answer (score 0):

The app had two build variants and the only difference was the database source file and the app name.
The first variant worked fine, but I started having this problem when I tried the other build variant.

I got it to work (and trace) correctly by Rebuilding the Project (Build > Rebuild Project).

Answer (score 0):

When compiling java bytecode to dex bytecode, Android Studio dexer may apply some optimizations and mangle all the return statements into one, and when you debug the code, it may look like it is randomly jumping between your case statements. It is not and you should not worry about it.

You say your "term" variable is "", so Android Studio is probably adding a return statement in incompleteSearch().

If the code installed on the device were to be somehow outdated when compared to the one you see on Android Studio, for example when you modify the code, attach the debugger to the old version you already installed, and step into that function, a popup will show saying "Source code does not match bytecode"

Comment: At the point of the "jumping" that message was not displayed, but tracing elsewhere I did get that warning so I suspected that was the problem.